# She said she was able to do it - two meanings?

Tags: meaning, modal-verbs

**Example 1**

> She said she could do it.

**Example 2**

> She said she was able to do it

I feel like Example 1 only have the meaning of "she said she had the ability to do it, but she didn't say whether she actually did it or not."

And Example 2 has two minutes

> (1) She said she actually did it but she didn't say whether she actually did it or not you.

> (2) She said she had the ability to do it.

Comment: Both examples are ambiguous. For example, in the first one, she might have said *"I **could** do it"* (perhaps tending to imply *"...but I don't want to, so I **won't**"*)  OR  *"I **can** do it"* (perhaps implying *"...and I **will** do it [soon]"*).

Comment: There is a further ambiguity. Are both the "shes" the same person? **Joan said "I can do it."** or **Joan said "Anne can do it"**

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is the same in both cases.

> She said she had the ability to do it.

Any further implications (whether she actually did it or not, whether I could also do it, if she still has the ability) are not given, though they might be given in the context.

The main difference is that "She could do it"  can be the conclusion of a (second) conditional, and so might be about the future. Again, to understand it as a conditional there would need to be context.